# how can i know if my array is consuming the data i try to send to it? swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

hi i am new to this swift and coding in general, i have created a tiny app that the user can take a photo form the photo library and type in a `title` and a `location` of the `image` and upload it to the `tableview`, but i have some problem and i dont really know what is the problem because iam new to this but there is no error in the code or warnings there is only problem really when the `user` press `Done/Upload`button nothing happens, my `tableview` dont update. Iam not sure if my `tableview` is not updating or if i even am sending the data over to my array... 
so how can i see what data is in my `array` and if iam even sending the data the right way?

Here is how iam inserting the `data`to the `array`

```
   @IBAction func doneEditing(_ sender: Any) {
        insertNewActy()
    }


   func insertNewActy(){

    addTitles = addTitle.text!
    addLocations = addLocation.text!
    newImages = newImage.image!

    let element = MyCellRows(image: newImages,
                             title: addTitles,
                             location: addLocations)

    myCellRows.insert(element, at: 0)

 }
```

and here is the code of my `array`: is my Array even set up the right way?

```
import UIKit

 var myCellRows: [MyCellRows] = []


class ActyViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


    func createMyCellArray() -> [MyCellRows] {

    var myCells: [MyCellRows] = []

    let dog = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Dog"),
                         title: "Dog",
                         location: "America")
    let cat = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cat"),
                         title: "Cat",
                         location: "Sweden")
    let rabbit = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Rabbit"),
                         title: "Rabbit",
                         location: "Germany")
    let tiger = MyCellRows(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Tiger"),
                         title: "Tiger",
                         location: "Africa")

    myCells.append(dog)
    myCells.append(cat)
    myCells.append(rabbit)
    myCells.append(tiger)


    return myCells

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myCellRows = createMyCellArray()



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}



}
```

this is my tableView code

```
extension ActyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myCellRows.count
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myActy = myCellRows[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ActyCellTableViewCell

    cell.setActy(actys: myActy)

    return cell
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200.0
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        myCellRows.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        myTableView.reloadData()
        }


}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewDidAppear(true)


   myTableView.reloadData()
}



}
```

Comment: You need to tell the table view about the new row after you update `myCellRows`.

Comment: sorry if iam asking for to much @rmaddy but do you know how do i do that? sense iam pretty new or what i can search for or anything that can help me to tell the tableview of the new row?

Comment: @rmaddy but my array is set up correctly and the way i send it the information right?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UITableView`. There are methods for inserting rows.

Comment: okey thanks @rmaddy

Comment: Not related and completely off topic: Tigers don't belong to Africa ;-)

Comment: @vadian hahahaha i just wrote something to test my "location" text if it worked xD

Answer (score -1):

I think you have confused your concepts a bit but you explained your problem well so you're off to a good start. I've rewritten parts of your code and left out the image part so you have a working table view before you continue:

```
struct Animal {
    var title: String
    var location: String
}

class ActyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var animals: [Animal] = [
        Animal(title: "Dog", location: "America"),
        Animal(title: "Cat", location: "Sweden"),
        Animal(title: "Rabbit", location: "Germany"),
        Animal(title: "Tiger", location: "Africa"),
    ]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "AnimalCell"
        let cell: UITableViewCell = {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) else {
                return UITableViewCell(style:.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
            }
            return cell
        }()

        cell.textLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row].title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = animals[indexPath.row].location

        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see above, you should separate your data from how you present your data, so I've made an array of `Animal` that keeps your data. Your tableview should have a `UITableViewDataSource` and will ask this data source for data using the two functions you can see.

Now you can add an animal to your list of animals and refresh the table

```
animals.append(Animal(title: "Elephant", location: "India"))
tableView.reloadData()
```

Hope that helps to get you going.

If your only problem is that your tableView isn't refreshing after you add the new data, make sure you call `reloadData()` after you update your array. If your `insertNewActy()` function is in the same ViewController as the rest of your code you should be able to change it to:

```
func insertNewActy(){

    addTitles = addTitle.text!
    addLocations = addLocation.text!
    newImages = newImage.image!

    let element = MyCellRows(image: newImages,
                            title: addTitles,
                            location: addLocations)

    myCellRows.insert(element, at: 0)
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: i understand this, i managed to make a tableview and insert only text before and now i want to make it so i insert an image aswell, look at my question i have uploaded my table view code in there, maybe its somthing wrong with the tableview code? this code is just underneth my array code

Comment: Do you call `tableView.reloadData()` somewhere after you add a row to your array?

Comment: @Tejre i dont really know how to do it "after" i have added the row... so i have just putted it in the `viewDidAppear` is that correct or must i realod the data some other way?

Comment: Ok, and you've made sure `viewDidAppear()` is called after you insert a new row in your array? A breakpoint in each function should verify that.

Comment: im not really sure how to do that. that why everything is hard for me because i know what iam going to do but i dont know how i will do it, like now i dont know how to reaload the data after i added the new information

Comment: I assume the table view is showing your initial four rows? It's when you try to insert more rows that nothing happens? For help on debugging, here's how to get started: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/quickstart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH7-SW3

Comment: @Tejre Yes it is Exactly what is going on and i have no clue whats wrong because i dont get any errors

Comment: Then it could be one of two things: either your array data is not updated or you are not calling `tableView.reloadData()` after. Either way: learn how to place breakpoints in Xcode, it's really not hard. The execution will stop and you will be able to examine your data at the points you want.

Comment: do you know how to make it so `tableview.reloadData()` is run after i add the new thing to the array? @Terje

Comment: I updated my answer above for you to try. Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much for your effort i will try this and se with the breakpoint if my tableview even updates efter i press done